# Reduce function in Racket?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm stuck 5 days with this task in Racket, does anybody know how can I approach it?

*Given a function of arity 2 and a list of `n` elements, return the evaluation of the string function of all the elements, for example:*

```
>(reduce + '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

55

> (reduce zip '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
'((1 (4 7)) (2 (5 8)) (3 (6 9)))
```

Comment: The sample output doesn't seem right, please check to see if it's correct. Also, post the implementation of `zip`.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go.

```
(define (reduce func list)
  (assert (not (null? list)))
  (if (null? (cdr list))
      (car list)
      (func (car list) (reduce func (cdr list)))))
```

Tests:

```
> (reduce + '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
55
> (reduce zip '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))
((1 (4 7)) (2 (5 8)) (3 (6 9)))
```

For completeness, an implementation for `zip` (one that assumes two lists and that your lists are all the same length) is:

```
(define (zip l1 l2) (map list l1 l2))
```

Comment: Ouch, hit by a sniper.  Down voted w/o an explanation - on a CORRECT answer no less.  Bring it on!

Comment: you're right, the answer seems correct. here ya go. :) Why ppl in [tag:scheme] don't upvote each other, I don't understand it. It's not like we have a large audience here. Could you show the definition of `zip` through? Or are you using a built-in? (well, obviously it's `(define (zip a b) (map list a b))`, but for the sake of completeness it should be inside the answer perhaps).

Comment: Thanks.  The same user asked a question on implementing `zip`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688944/zip-function-in-racket-scheme

Comment: already did. :) this was assumed to be homework, so giving full code isn't advisable... :) ... so you mean you're using same `zip` here as you gave there? still perhaps it's better to include the code (or its skeleton) here as well. (?)

Answer (score 9):

You can express it in terms of [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29):

```
(define (reduce f xs)
  (and (not (empty? xs)) (foldl f (first xs) (rest xs))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define reduce
  (λ (f init ls)
    (if (empty? ls)
        init
        (reduce f (f init (first ls)) (rest ls)))))
```