# zip function in Racket/Scheme

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

*Given two lists, return a list whose elements are lists of size two, such that for the `i`-th list, the first element is the `i`-th element of the first original list, and the second element is the `i`-th element of the second original list. If one list is smaller than the other, the resulting list is of the smallest size; and so if one of the lists is empty, return an empty list.* For example:

```
> (zip '(1 2) '(3 4))
'((1 3) (2 4))

> (zip '(1 2 3) '())
'()
> (zip '() '(4 5 6))
'()
> (zip '(8 9) '(3 2 1 4))
'((8 3) (9 2))
> (zip '(8 9 1 2) '(3 4))
'((8 3) (9 4))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please post the code! otherwise people will think that you want to get you homework done for free ;)

Answer (score 15):

Try so:

```
(map cons '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
```

or so:

```
(map list '(1 2 3) '(a b c))
```

---

```
(define zip (lambda (l1 l2) (map list l1 l2)))

->(zip '(1 2 3) '(x y z))
'((1 x) (2 y) (3 z))
```

Comment: `(map cons '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) ; ==> ((1 . a) (2 . b) (3 . c))`, not the desired result  `((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))`

Comment: Any function can be used there, as time as the function has 2 input parameters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the lambda in the `zip` definition? It seems like `(define (zip l1 l2) (map list l1 l2))` would do just as well... ?

Comment: What you wrote is a syntactic sugar for what I wrote. The form you wrote is expanded in what I wrote during preprocessing. But a better syntactic sugar for composition is present in Haskell under the concept of composition (`o`  operator) or under the concept of `section`.  In that case there is no need to explicitly pass the name of arguments, as haskell does that for you in the preprocessing.

Comment: I don't think does the right thing in Racket at least - you only tested the condition where the input lengths are equal. Additionally `zip` is typically understood to work on streams as well so you would for example create an indexed pair with `(zip '(1 2 3) (in-naturals))`

Answer (score 4):

Because you didn't post the code you've written, I'm guessing this is homework. I'll give you some hints to get started, this is the general structure of the solution, fill-in the blanks - it'll be much more fun if you reach the correct answer by your own means!

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((<???> lst1)  ; if the first list is empty
         <???>)        ; then return the empty list 
        ((<???> lst2)  ; if the second list is empty
         <???>)        ; then also return the empty list 
        (else          ; otherwise
         (cons (list   ; cons a list with two elements:
                <???>  ; the first from the first list
                <???>) ; and the first from the second list
               (zip <???> <???>))))) ; advance recursion over both lists
```

I tested the above implementation with the sample inputs, and the results are as expected:

```
(zip '(1 2) '(3 4))
=> '((1 3) (2 4))

(zip '(1 2 3) '())
=> '()

(zip '() '(4 5 6))
=> '()

(zip '(8 9) '(3 2 1 4))
=> '((8 3) (9 2))

(zip '(8 9 1 2) '(3 4))
=> '((8 3) (9 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've solved the problem for the first element then you can recurse on the rest of the list:

```
(define (zip l1 l2)
  (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
      '()
      (cons (list (car l1) (car l2))
            (zip  (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))
```

provided you handle the base case where either list is empty.

```
> (zip '(1 2 3 4) '(a b))
((1 a) (2 b))
> (zip '() '(a b))
()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `map` implementation stops at the shortest list, then `zip` can be defined with `map`, Scheme's `list` procedure and `apply`. Here's a hint:

```
(define (zip . lsts)
  (apply <??> <??> lsts))
```

[SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)'s `map` is sufficient. So in Racket you add `(require (only-in srfi/1 map))`

Answer (score 1):

If we accept Racket functions, and also relax the requirement of returning 2-tuples in favor of a more general `zip`, then I would check out [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29). Here are examples zipping or interleaving two or three lists, *stopping at the shortest list*.

```
(define l1 '(a b c))
(define l2 '(1 2 3))
(define l3 '(true false))

;; → '((a 1 true) (b 2 false))
(for/list ([i l1] [j l2] [k l3])
          (list i j k))

;; → '((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
(for/list ([i l1] [j l2])
          (list i j))

;; → '()
(for/list ([i l1] [j l2] [k null])
          (list i j k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I came across the same exercise and did my own implementation which is different from all the ones people posted here. All the other answers are great. I really liked the most voted one from @Alinsoar.

Definitely, the other answers are actually better than my implementation. But I will post it anyway. Maybe, this can help someone trying to learn Racket.

```
(define (shorter-list xs ys)
  (if (> (length xs) (length ys))
      ys
      xs))

(define (zip xs ys)
  (cond [(null? (shorter-list xs ys)) null]
        [true (cons (list (car xs) (car ys)) (zip (cdr xs) (cdr ys)))]))
```